# Change default starting directory of cmd.exe on windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

How can I change the default starting directory of cmd.exe on Windows 10 when opened using the key sequence `Super-x c` (by "Super" I mean the windows key, whatever its name is)?  I can change the the link in the start menu by modifying the entry in

`"%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk"`

with visual basic or otherwise, but it doesn't effect the normal way I open the prompt which is the key sequence above.  I would just like to change the working directory to the value of an environment variable I set as "%HOME%".

Comment: Check `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3"` folder. [Another question, the same answer at SU](http://superuser.com/a/1040974/376602).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JosefZ showed in his comment, the directory to look in was `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3"`.  Just to wrap up the question, I was able to modify the shortcuts with a simple batch script,
Basically, just the following, which will modify the starting directory of the link in the start menu, as well as the `win-x` links for user/admin.

```
:: preamble stuff
set "startup=%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools"
call :modifyLink "%startup%\Command Prompt.lnk"
call :modifyLink "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\01 - Command Prompt.lnk"
call :modifyLink "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group3\02 - Command Prompt.lnk"

:EOF

:modifyLink
set tscript="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo.Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") > "%tscript%"
echo.Set shortcut = sh.CreateShortcut("%~1") >> "%tscript%"
echo.shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "%HOME%" >> "%tscript%"
echo.shortcut.Save >> "%tscript%"

cscript /nologo "%tscript%"
del "%tscript%"
```